# Core Data Values Accessed by Multiple Users when logged in (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app where a UITableView is used to represent a  friends list. Now, this table is updated by values stored in core data, and I'm downloading friend values to core data via Parse. Instead of accessing Parse to update the tableView directly, I decided to update Core Data and then the tableView because I need the friend information in other parts of the app, and thought it would be more efficient to use Core Data than to have calls to Parse again and again. Everything works fine!

However, my app has a log in system before users can use the app. And when I created another dummy user to test it, I found that the friend values stored in Core Data by my actual account were being used to update the friend list tableView! When actually the tableView should be empty (new user).

I don't know exactly how Core Data works but I figure it uses some segment of the device's memory to store entities. My question is this, is it possible to use Core Data to store private information related to a particular user that can't be accessed by other users that log into the same device? Or should I continue to make calls to Parse whenever I need information?

Hope you guys understood my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iOS is not a multi-user system. Your app stores its files in a sandboxed folder structure and this sandbox is independent of any user logins you have implemented in your app.

When a new user logs in (or, if you prefer, when a user logs out) it is up to you to remove any data you have stored in Core Data that you don't want another user to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Parse can save data offline by [Local Storage](http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/) or cache the request by [Cache Policy](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/easy-caching-with-parse/)

They are much faster than creating your own database (by CoreData).